# Number of documents where a field appears - MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, query-optimization

My java application uses a map-reduce to retrieve a couple of string `<field's name, types>` from a MongoDB collection. 
For example I have:

```
<_id,ObjectId>
<name, String,Object>
<dateOfBirth, String,Date>
```

It means that in my collection there are documents where `_id` field is just an `ObjectId`, `name` is a `String`or an `Object` and `dateOfBirth` can be both `String` and `Date`. 
Now, my target is to find the number of documents where a field appears. So I wrote this java method

```
public int countFields(String s) {

        DBObject query = new BasicDBObject(s,new BasicDBObject("$exists",1));

        int n = coll.find(query).count();
        return n;

    }
```

This method works correctly: given in input a string representing a field's name, it finds the number of documents where the string appears. 
So, for each field I have something like this:

```
<_id, 500>
<name,340>
<dateOfBirth, 100>
```

It means that `_id` is present in 500 documents of my collection, `name` in 340 and `dateOfBirth` in 100.

Suppose I have to run this method for all fields of a collection: it is not efficient!
 For example with about 30k documents in my collection, I run `countFields(s)` method for each field `s` and it needs about 3 seconds to retrieve the number of documents where a field appears. 
What can I do to have better performance on this query?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple map-reduce to count all top-level fields in the collection:

```
db.coll.mapReduce(
    function(){
        for (var field in this) { 
            emit(field, 1); 
        }            
    },
    function(field, times) {
        return Array.sum(times);
    }
)
```

Comment: Ok, do you think map reduce is better in terms of complexity?

Comment: I did not profile, but I would assume so. Also, if you don't need all fields, you can limit it to the specific list.

Comment: Unfortunately I need all fields, but I'm going to test map-redue. Thanks fot your advice.

Comment: It works just for top-level fields. If I create a map-reduce that uses recursion to count also not top-level fields, do you think can I have an improvement of performance?

Comment: I am sure counting nested fields will be slower than counting top-level ones. Apart from that, you will need to define a function for recursive calls, define a syntax how to represent nested fields, and implement logic to handle arrays.

Comment: Yes, I made a similar work to retrieve fields' name at any depth level. I wonder whether a recursive mapreduce can have better performance than standard query : `db.coll.find(field:{$exists:1}).count()`. 
I'm going to try with a recursive mapreduce. Then I'll give you a feedback. Thanks for your kindness.